# to check a condition in any case sensitive in php

Tags: php

I have a condition like

```
if ( ( $red == '50' && $city == 'Bali' ) ||  ( $red == '50' && $city == 'BALI' ) ) {
    //My code here
}
```

How can i combine the condition and write a single line. Is there any function in php ?

Comment: Make word lowercase (uppercase) and check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just convert the string to either upper or lower case and then do your comparison:

```
if ( $red == '50' && strtolower($city) === 'bali' ) {
    //My code here
}
```

or

```
if ( $red == '50' && strtoupper($city) === 'BALI' ) {
    //My code here
}
```

Comment: I see extra `)`

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. If only Stack Overflow had a built in IDE for textfields... :)

Comment: I see extra `(` and `)`. Btw I would use `mb_strtolower($city, 'utf-8')` - just in case OP is going to use non-ASCII city names.

Answer (score 9):

there is a function for completely case-insensitive comparison function called `strcasecmp`, which would match Bali and BaLi and BALI and any other case-combination, assuming ascii/ascii-subset of utf8

```
if ($red == '50' && 0 === strcasecmp($city,'Bali') )
```

- edit: as @Jiri Hrazdil pointed out, if you are comparing non-ascii characters (like Æ Ø Å æ ø å ), you should probably use the mb_ functions, like `if ($red == '50' && mb_strtolower($city,'UTF-8') ==='åsgårdstrand')` - if you are using UTF-8 specifically, you could also use preg_match with the `/ui` modifiers, like `if ($red == '50' && preg_match('/^'.preg_quote('Bøli').'$/ui',$city) )`

  - but preg_match only supports UTF-8 unicode, not any other characterset. mb_ supports all major, and many rare character-sets

Answer (score 1):

**If** you want **exact match** means **don't** want to **convert** `$city` to **upper case** or **lower case** letter then you can do like this:-

```
if ( $red == '50' && ($city == 'Bali' || $city == 'BALI' ) ) {
    //My code here
}
```